# Cannot Delete VNet/Subnet Due To Reference To Deleted App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, vnet

I am unable to delete the 'default' subnet from a VNet that I am no longer using. The error is: 
"Subnet default is in use by /subscriptions/{guid}/resourceGroups/mpi-prod-westeurope-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/mpi-web-asp and
cannot be deleted."

The problem is mpi-web-asp is an App Service plan that was deleted about a week ago. I attempted to create a new App Service Plan with the same name however, as expected, that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove the App Service plan `mpi-web-asp` in the [Azure resource explorer](https://resources.azure.com/), navigate to the path, `/subscriptions/{guid}/resourceGroups/mpi-prod-westeurope-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/mpi-web-asp` to find the app service plan. Get more details about using [this tool](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-resource-explorer-a-new-tool-to-discover-the-azure-api/).

Click **Read/Write** tab to enter the edit mode, then click **Action(POST, DELETE)**, you could click **Delete** to delete the old resources.  After this, Try to remove the default subnet again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply however as mentioned my App Service Plan has already been deleted and it does not show up in the Azure Resource Explorer.

Comment: How did you remove this subnet? I have tried to follow your steps, new Vnet integration---subnet, then remove the app service plan(this will require to remove all web app service hosting on this service plan). After removing all app services and app service plan, I could delete subnet from VNet-subnets--right-click the specific subnet to delete. Have you tried to delete this subnet in Azure Resource Explorer?

Comment: I did not remove the subnet - that is the point, I cannot remove it via the Azure Portal, Powershell, or Azure Resource Explorer.

Comment: So strange. Unless you still have old resources is referencing the default subnet. Before you said, you recreated the same name app service plan, ensure you have removed the app service plan, any resources associated with this app service plan and subnet, try it again? check you have signed in the correct subscription and tenant, resource group. If still no effect, it would be better to contact Azure support to check your subscription.